# simple way to provide dynamic margin to vaadin element

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin6

is there any way to provide a dynamic margin to vaadin component like component `component.setLeftMargin(10);`
I know I can set margin for horizontal layout but I want to set it to every element
?

Comment: just adapt your css?! .v-horizontallayout{ margin-left: 10px}

Answer (score 2):

There is a method that you can use ComponentPosition.
Gets the position of a component in the layout. Returns null if component
is not attached to the layout.

```
this.getPosition(tsheet).setCSSString("top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px");
```